# Directed paths in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I am facing a seemingly simple issue. I want to traverse the nodes of a `Neo4j` graph, using the traversal Java API. I want to include only paths where all relationships have the same direction, though. If I do something like

```
db.traversalDescription().relationships(<type>, Direction.BOTH)
```

paths like

```
[a]-[:TYPE]->[b]<-[:TYPE]-[c]
```

are included as well which I don't want. I only want paths like

```
[a]-[:TYPE]->[b]-[:TYPE]->[c]
[a]<-[:TYPE]-[b]<-[:TYPE]-[c]
```

Can anybody help? It seems like the solution should be quite simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Detailing Wes' idea a little bit. In your custom `PathEvaluator` you need to set branch state to remember the direction of the first relationship. All subsequent visits check if the last relationship matches the direction. In pseudo code:

```
class SameDirectionPathEvaluator implements PathEvaluator<Direction> {

   public Evaluation evaluate(Path path, BranchState<Direction> state) {
      if (path.length()==0) {
         return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
      } else if (path.length()==1) {
         state.setState(getDirectionOfLastRelationship(path));
         return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
      } else {
         if (state.getState().equals(getDirectionOfLastRelationship(path)) {
            return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
         } else {
            return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_PRUNE;
         }
      }
   }

   private Direction getDirectionOfLastRelationship(Path path) {
      assert path.length() > 0;
      Direction direction = Direction.INCOMING
      if (path.endNode().equals(path.lastRelationship().getEndNode()) {
        direction = Direction.OUTGOING;
      }
      return direction;
   }

}
```

Please note I did not compile or test the code above - it's just for sketching the idea.

## UPDATE

It seems there is a more efficient way to do this. Since traversals use expanders before evaluators are invoked it makes more sense to implement this behaviour in an expander:

```
     class ConstantDirectionExpander implements PathExpander<STATE>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Relationship> expand(Path path, BranchState<STATE> state) {
            if (path.length()==0) {
                return path.endNode().getRelationships(types);
            } else {
                Direction direction = getDirectionOfLastRelationship(path);
                return path.endNode().getRelationships(direction, types);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public PathExpander<STATE> reverse() {
            return this;
        }

        private Direction getDirectionOfLastRelationship(Path path) {
            assert path.length() > 0;
            Direction direction = Direction.INCOMING;
            if (path.endNode().equals(path.lastRelationship().getEndNode())) {
                direction = Direction.OUTGOING;
            }
            return direction;
        }
    }
```

In your traversal you need use a `InitialBranchSate`:

```
TraversersDescription td = graphDatabaseService.traversalDescriptioin().
  .expand(new ConstantDirectionExpander(reltype))
  .traverse(startNode)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks like something that should work. I'll give it a try.

Comment: This is a nice one for a cookbook somewhere. :)

Comment: already sent a PR, hopefully we will see it directly in Neo4j :-)

Answer (score 3):

The way I can think of is you'd implement a [PathEvaluator](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/PathEvaluator.html), which scans the path and checks that the nodes are pointing all the same direction. Then you can add it to your `TraversalDescription` with `.evaluator()`.

There may be a fancier way, though.. you're right, this does seem like it should be built-in.

Comment: Yes, that is something that came to my mind as well. I actually don't need to check the whole path, since I am adding one relationship at a time, therefore it is enough to check whether the last two relationships have the same direction. However, this is not something that the Java API would allow to be written in elegant and readable way.

Comment: Or use two traversers one for each direction?

Comment: I don't want to use two traversers, sice then, thay may encounter one path twice, each traverser from one direction and that is not acceptable for me.

Comment: The most clean way of implementing this I can imagine, is to implement custom PathExpander, which expands only in desired direction. I would do such a thing myself (and even contribute it to neo4j if so desired) however, I wanted to ask first, whether there is more straighforward way. Also, I got a bit lost among all the existing implementations of PathExpanders so I would appreciate a little hint where to start, which PathExpander implementation I should extend.